# ReactPHP - Timing the length of time it took to send a UDP packet?

Tags: php, reactphp

I'm currently using the ReactPHP Event Loop and ReactPHP Datagram (which can be found here: https://github.com/reactphp/datagram).

At the moment, I'm using the Datagram client to connect to a UDP server and send packets to it every ~20ms, however, I need to time how long it takes to send a packet. Is this possible with ReactPHP?

Comment: What condition, exactly, are you using to consider a packet "sent"?  Remember that with UDP, you're in a fire-and-forget situation.

Comment: @timdev not really sure how to explain it haha, in C# `int bytesSent = await _udp.Send(buffer, 0, buffer.Length).ConfigureAwait(false);` would return the bytes sent which is what I would like (but doesn't need to return the bytes sent)